# How to check whether a NSPoint lays inside a NSRect

Tags: cocoa, points, rectangles

I've created a mutable array containing NSRect values. I want to check whether the NSPoint I created is within this rectangle. What is the best way to do this in cocoa.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

From the [Foundation Functions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsrect):

```
BOOL NSPointInRect (
   NSPoint aPoint,
   NSRect aRect
);
```

"Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given point is in a given rectangle."

Answer (score 2):

A valid question because not everyone realises that there are a great many helper functions provided in the [Foundation NSRect Extensions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsrect) file which save you having to re-invent the wheel all over the place.

Have a quick read through the reference to see all the different places it can help. I found it very useful when starting out.

Comment: Link is no longer valid. I guess that's to be expected after 8 years though.

Comment: Thanks for the Heads up - I've updated the link to the more modern reference.

Answer (score 1):

NSPointInRect?